# "Error with Permissions-Policy header", when using Chromedriver to a Headless Browser

Tags: selenium

On Selenium, I am using chromedriver version 89 and my chrome browser version 89.0. too. When I run my code on a headless browser, I got an error; turn chrome to a headless browser to test the result. Here is my script-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which 

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

chrome_path = which("chromedriver")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com/")

search_input = driver.find_element_by_id("search_form_input_homepage")
search_input.send_keys("My User Agent")

search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

***And here is the VSCODE Terminal Output,***

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57195/devtools/browser/7464cfb0-5b3c-497d-a768-6eae3bb5b59b
[0408/112137.788:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0408/112138.552:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0408/112139.176:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0408/112139.483:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
```

[VSCode Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM4vH.png)

Answer (score 13):

This is the new header used to block Google's new tracking technology called Federated Cohorts of Learning (FLoC).

[About FLoC](https://web.dev/floc/)

The header is being used by DDG to block FLoC tracking.

[DuckDuckGo Announces Plans to Block Google’s FLoC](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/duckduckgo-announces-plans-to-block-googles-floc/401993/)

You get the same warning in Chrome dev tools if you access any website that blocks FLoC.

To block Google's FLoC on your own website, add the following header:

```
permissions-policy: interest-cohort=()
```

Comment: This post clarifies some of the misinformation about this header. Worth reading before adding the header to your site: https://seirdy.one/2021/04/16/permissions-policy-floc-misinfo.html

Comment: Looks like GitLab does this wholesale... including in your Gitlab Pages https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/floc.html
Gitlab Pages are mostly free, but this does mean you may have practically no data on visitors at all, without cloudflare or some stateful backend.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to remove those warning messages then add

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=1')
```

More info here [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#log-level)

```
log-level: Sets the minimum log level.
Valid values are from 0 to 3: 

    INFO = 0 (default)
    WARNING = 1
    LOG_ERROR = 2
    LOG_FATAL = 3
```